# How to multiple two input and addition the third input on keypress

Tags: javascript

How to multiply two input and addition the third input on keypress 
I have a Three input field need to multiple first two input and addition of third input then show the result field 
HTML code:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="3" class="form-control" name="making_charge" oninput="calculate()" placeholder="Making Charge" id="box3" required />

 <input type="text" tabindex="3" class="form-control" name="total_price" placeholder="Total Price" id="result" readonly  />

function calculate() {
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
        var myBox3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2 + myBox3;
        result.value = myResult; 
    }
```

Comment: Please at least _tag_ appropriately – this has nothing whatsoever to do with `php`. (Tags edited.)

Comment: You seem to have the basic parts there already (the usual addition-of-strings issue is probably not present here to begin with, because it starts with a multiplication), so what is the actual _problem_ now? Please go read [ask] and give proper problem descriptions, instead of asking “how to” questions.

Comment: Is `<input type="button" onclick="calculate()">`what you are looking for?

Comment: var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2 + myBox3; Is this Correct or not?

Comment: @kesavan so what is your actual problem which you did not state in your question.

Comment: How multiply two inputs then addition of the third input

Comment: But what is wrong with your code? ;) That is all we are trying to get you to say. You never stated the problem you have. We are guessing what your issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `value` is a string so you need to covert it to a number to do mathematical operations on it.

You can do it with a `+`, `Number()`, `parseInt()`, `parseFloat()`

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = +document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var myBox2 = +document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var myBox3 = +document.getElementById('box3').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2 + myBox3;
  result.value = myResult;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" tabindex="3" class="form-control" name="making_charge" oninput="calculate()" placeholder="Making Charge" id="box1" required />

<input type="text" tabindex="3" class="form-control" name="making_charge" oninput="calculate()" placeholder="Making Charge" id="box2" required />

<input type="text" tabindex="3" class="form-control" name="making_charge" oninput="calculate()" placeholder="Making Charge" id="box3" required />

<input name="total_price" placeholder="Total Price" id="result" readonly />
```